# How to use the output vector of a matlab function as an input for a lookup table in the same Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am basically using a 1-D array, manipulating it using Matlab function and the output is also a 1-D array. I want to use this as the input for a lookup table in the same simulink model. Thereafter, I want this 24-hr time-series output from the lookup table to fed to another function.

Any suggestions to achieve this time series input without using the lookup table is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Option A, Easy Solution: share variables via the workspace:

```
%%
LUT_BREAKPOINTS=<something>
LUT_VALUES=function_that_manipulates_1D_Array()
SIGNAL=<24_Hs_Signal>
%%
sim('model_name')
%%
<Process model output>
%%
```

model_name Uses `FromWorkspace` to load *SIGNAL*, `ToWorkspace` to export the simulation output, Use a 1D loot, configure it with *LUT_BREAKPOINTS* and *LUT_VALUES*.

---

Option B, simulink multirate processing.

- Configure Simulink to use discrete fixed steps as solver.
- Use a Direct_Look_Up_table with a Pre_Look_Up, configure it to accept
  the table as an external input...
- Feed it with a MatlabFunctionBlock that manipulates your 1D Array.
- Feed the MatlabFunctionBlock with the original Array,
- Feed the Pre_Look_Up with SIGNAL.
- Use the output of the Direct_Look_Up_table on a Frame_buffer, with
  24Hs of samples as frame.
- Use the output of the Frame_buffer to feed another MatlabFunctionBlock with your final processing.